# Slide different DIVs using different buttons but with the same ID with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, expand

I have the following script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.expandButton').click(function() {
         $('.expandableSection').toggle("slide");
    });
});
```

I want to apply it to multiple sections. The issue is that every time I click on the .expandButton button, all sections slide instead of making that specific section to slide. This makes sense, but what I need is to have only that section sliding.

My sections look like this:

```
<h1 class="expandButton"></h1>     
<div class="expandableSection">
</div>

<h1 class="expandButton"></h1>     
<div class="expandableSection">
</div>

<h1 class="expandButton"></h1>     
<div class="expandableSection">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a context based lookup for the `expandableSection` element. In your case the target `expandableSection` is the parent of the clicked `expandButton` element so you can use `this`(which refer to the clicked `button`) and then find the target `expandableSection` using `.closest()` or `.parent()`(since `expandableSection` is the direct parent of the button)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.expandButton').click(function() {
    $(this).next('.expandableSection').toggle("slide");
  });
});
```

```css
.expandButton {
  height: 20px;
  background: lightgrey;
}
.expandableSection {
  height: 20px;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="expandButton"></h1> 
<div class="expandableSection">
</div>

<h1 class="expandButton"></h1> 
<div class="expandableSection">
</div>

<h1 class="expandButton"></h1> 
<div class="expandableSection">
</div>
```

Comment: Not working for me. As soon as I added $(this).closest or .parent nothing happens anymore

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```js
 $('.expandButton').click(function() {
         $(this).parent().toggle("slide");
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="expandableSection">
   <h1 class="expandButton">sdfsdf</h1>
</div>
<div class="expandableSection">
   <h1 class="expandButton">dsfsdfs</h1>
</div>
<div class="expandableSection">
   <h1 class="expandButton"> sfasdas</h1>
</div>
<div class="expandableSection">
   <h1 class="expandButton">sdfsdf</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in the explanation. Each h1 goes before each opening div, therefore the div is not the h1's parent anymore... any solution? Updating the question now